# Some text is garbled when reading PDF text with iText7

Tags: java, c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I read PDF text with itext7 7.1.14 and itext7.font-asian 7.1.14 from nuget in C#, but some of the text, such as the date, is garbled as shown in the image below. Is there any way to fix this?[image]

```
var req = WebRequest.Create("https://www.release.tdnet.info/inbs/140120210208458149.pdf");
req.Timeout = 5000;

using (var res = req.GetResponse())
using (var st = res.GetResponseStream())
using (var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(st)))
{
    var text = "";

    //PDFのページ分繰り返す
    for (var page = 1; page <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
    {
        //PDFから文字列を抽出
        text += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDoc.GetPage(page)) + "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a link to the PDF file

Comment: It is the same as the URL in the source code.